# If/Else Statement's Shell Comparing more than 2 Values?

Tags: bash, shell, date, if-statement, terminal

Quick question regrading if/else statements in shell, Right now I am trying to test if two different values are equal to a third

```
echo "CompareDateValues"
if [ "${TodaysDate}" = "${prevDate}" & "${currDate}" ]; then
    echo "Dates Are A Match : TodaysDate:${TodaysDate} = savedStateRunDates:${prevDate}"
else
    echo "Dates Are Not A Match : TodaysDate:${TodaysDate} = savedStateRunDates:${prevDate}"
    echo Exit
    exit 1
fi
```

As you can see from the code above I am trying to test if prevdate and currdate match Todaysdate but I can seem to get it working any help would be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use two conditions:

```
if [ "$TodaysDate" = "$prevDate" ] && [ "$TodaysDate" = "$currDate" ] ; then
```

or the `-a` operator (not recommended)

```
if [ "$TodaysDate" = "$prevDate" -a "$TodaysDate" = "$currDate" ] ; then
```

or, if you're in bash, switch to `[[ ... ]]` conditions:

```
if [[ $TodaysDate = $prevDate && $TodaysDate = $currDate ]] ; then
```

Comment: Don't use `-a`; even the POSIX standard recommends using two separate commands.

Answer (score 1):

```
if test "$TodaysDate" = "$prevDate" && test "$TodaysDate" = "$currDate"; then ...
```

Comment: `if [ "$TodaysDate" = "$prevDate" ] && [ "$TodaysDate" = "$currDate" ] ; then ...`

Comment: `if [ "$TodaysDate" = "$prevDate" -a "$TodaysDate" = "$currDate" ] ; then ...`

Comment: You don't even need that `if`, like this:
`[ "$TodaysDate" = "$prevDate" ] && [ "$TodaysDate" = "$currDate" ] && {  echo "Dates Are Matching"; } || { echo "Dates Do Not Match"; exit 1; } || exit 1`  - note the second `exit 1`

Comment: And now without `&&` , like this: `if [ "$TodaysDate-$TodaysDate" = "$prevDate-$currDate" ] ; then ...`

Comment: @pelya: why are you providing your answers as comments? There are many different ways to write this.

Comment: One valid answer was already provided, and I don't feel like those variants deserve to be separate answers. If the question was like, "what is the most convoluted way performing conditional operation you've seen in a shell script", all those comments would be valid answers.